# Chess notation: TypeScript template literals: TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent

Tags: typescript, types, pattern-matching

I'm trying to represent [Algebraic Chess Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) with TypeScript [Template Literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

Types I used:

```js
export type ChessPiece = 'P' | 'K' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'B' | 'N';
export type ChessX = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h';
export type ChessY = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8;

export type AlgebraicMoveNotationDisambiguate = '' | ChessX | ChessY | `${ChessX}${ChessY}`;
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationBase = `${ChessPiece | ChessX}${AlgebraicMoveNotationDisambiguate}${'x' | ''}${ChessX}${ChessY}`;
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationPromote = `${ChessX}8${ChessPiece}`;
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationDecoration = `${'' | '+' | '#'}`;
export type AlgebraicMoveNotation = 'O-O' | 'O-O-O' | `${AlgebraicMoveNotationBase|AlgebraicMoveNotationPromote}${AlgebraicMoveNotationDecoration}`;
```

This gives an error on line 6 (`AlgebraicMoveNotationBase`):

```
TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.
```

I understand this is quite a complex expression and calculating all possible values all the time might be not feasible (I did the math, there's about 3.5 billion combinations in the final type `AlgebraicMoveNotation`).

My question is - is there a way to configure TS to only evaluate assigned values without trying to understand **all** possible types, f.e.:

```js
// Example 1 =======

const someMove: AlgebraicMoveNotation = 'exd5'; // <- Checks provided literal is valid

// Example 2 =======

const validateMoves(moves: AlgebraicMoveNotation[]): void {
    // ...
}

validateMoves([ // <- Checks provided literals in array are valid
    'Nf6+',
    'a8Q',
    'Qexe1#',
]);
```

I tried to check similar errors but didn't find anything related.

---

Simpler example for easier reproduction:

```js
export type ChessPiece = 'P' | 'K' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'B' | 'N';
export type ChessX = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h';
export type ChessY = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8;

export type AlgebraicMoveNotationDisambiguate = '' | ChessX | ChessY | `${ChessX}${ChessY}`;
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationCapture = '' | 'x';
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationBase = `${ChessPiece | ChessX}${AlgebraicMoveNotationDisambiguate}${AlgebraicMoveNotationCapture}${ChessX}${ChessY}`;
```

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: What you can do is instead of generating all 3.5b possible moves at compile time, is check the given values at compile time.

Comment: Isn't your representation already incorrect because it only includes black pieces and allows promotion of pawns to pawns?

Comment: @kelsny Well, yes, but that's completely beside the question

Comment: @kelsny Of course I know I can check at runtime, but that doesn't help. I wanted to know why is there such a limitation and if it's configurable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Note that @kelsny did not mention runtime. What you can do is write `CheckAlgebraicMoveNotation<T>` such that `T extends CheckAlgebraicMoveNotation<T>` if and only if `T` would be assignable to the too-complex `AlgebraicMoveNotation`.  I would write an answer showing how, but apparently your notation isn't really correct so I'm not sure I want to go through the exercise. Could you perhaps [edit] to present a [mre] with a more simply defined (but still too big for a union) type and then we can show how to convert it to a generic check?

Comment: @jcalz Whoops, I thought they meant runtime because they mentioned "compile time" twice, which was confusing to me. I've added a simpler example which should produce the same error.

Comment: So you could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpQoXW) maybe, although one would need to check for edge cases, and it's possible to change it so that the error message for bad inputs mentions something less opaque than `never`... but that's the basic idea. Does that fully address the question? If so I (or maybe @kelsny) could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot! The link you provided was very helpful (should've spent a little more time learning TS, sorry). I've posted an answer that works for me.

Comment: Self-answers are absolutely fine, but you should make sure to actually explain what's going on for the benefit of future readers.  This includes links to documentation, etc.  If you can't do that, do you want one of us to write up our own answer?

Comment: @jcalz Well, I understand the syntax, I've dealt with this before. But I'm not sure I understand the reason why this works and my previous solution doesn't. If you'd be so kind to write an answer, I'd be more than happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going over the specific type function for chess moves, which is already written in the other answer, I'll talk about the general class of problem.

TypeScript is unable to represent [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with more than approximately 100,000 members.  That's plenty for many purposes, but when [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) were introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) it made it possible to easily generate huge unions by concatenating unions-of-string-[literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) together.  If you a type `M` which is a union of  string literal types, and a type `N` which is a union of   string literal types, then the template literal type `` `${M}${N}` `` will be a union of ×  string literal types.  This very quickly gets out of hand as you repeat concatenations: concatenate  copies of `N` together and you'll get a union of  string literals.  Even for modestly small  and  you will quickly exceed the language's capacity to represent unions.

Like most such limits of the language, this is not configurable.  Generally speaking they are considered implementation details of the compiler that are not meant to be tweaked by users.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#45025](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45025) at the end of the description, for example.)  Large unions are taxing on compiler resources as it is, and increasing the limit would almost certainly just make things worse, so you could expect the compiler to become unusably slow or crash instead of issuing a warning.  So this is not an option.

---

Instead you will generally need a different approach. Generating every possible valid string literal type in a giant union isn't needed if all you want to do is check individual string literal types for validity. Checking membership in a set might be conceptually simple, but often it's a lot easier to implement a predicate instead.  (If I ask you if `"abc"` has three letters, you do *not* want to first generate the set of all three letter words.)

This means you can change from

```
type ValidString = ⋯;
```

to a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like

```
type ValidateString<T extends string> = ⋯;
```

where `T extends ValidateString<T>` if and only if `T extends ValidString` would have been true.  Then `Validate<T>` string acts like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on a type `T`.  To avoid having to write out the type argument yourself, you can make a helper function to infer it.

The ideal helper function would look like

```
const validateString = 
  <T extends ValidateString<T>>(t: T) => t;
```

but this will usually set off circularity detectors.  You can rephrase it to something like

```
const validateString = 
  <T extends string>(t: T & ValidateString<T>) => t;
```

or even

```
const validateString = <T extends string>(
  t: T extends ValidateString<T> ? T : ValidateString<T>
) => t;
```

which will allow the compiler to infer `T` from the value of `t` and then check it with `ValidateString<T>`.

And so, instead of writing

```
const str: ValidString = "⋯";  // need huge union
```

you would write

```
const str = validateString("⋯"); // only check the passed-in string
```

which isn't very different.

---

As for the general approach to converting from a big union to a constraint, you can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to *parse* your candidate string.  If you had something like

```
type ValidString = `${M}${N}${O}`
```

you might change it to

```
type ValidateString<T extends string> =
  T extends `${M}${infer _NO}` ?
  _NO extends `${N}${infer __O}` ?
  __O extends `${O}` ? T :
  never : never : never;
```

That splits the string into chunks, first seeing if it is `M` followed by the rest of the string which we call `_NO`... then seeing if `_NO` is `N` followed by the rest of the string which we call `__O`, and finally seeing if `__O` is `O` after all.  Each of these steps only deals with unions the sizes of `M`, `N`, and `O` without multiplying them together.

There are alternatives to `never` which can make error messages more palatable, but they get more difficult to write.  The goal is to make it so that `ValidateString<T>` produces the "closest" valid string to `T`, for some heuristic idea of "close".  That way when you call `validateString("inkorrekt")` the compiler will give you an error message of the form `'"inkorrekt" is not assignable to "correct"'` which will hopefully prompt you to fix it.  I'm not going to go into how to do it for the chess example or for the general problem... the tricky part is that finding the failed partial matches can create unions, and you don't want big unions in your output or you run the risk of hitting the limits again.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAslC8UBEMlQD7JgQzZlARnlgMZIDcAsAFCiRQByCyDxSDuGLRX7ZVtcNADyzJMLbDO+YTxlkaNOtABq2ADYBLACYBlYACdNAOwDmzAAYASAN4wAvrYaObw+xcXUlQqGq3bsYAh9IzMAHgAVKAgADyDjbQBnKETDE1MAPgQaKCgo2PikqGs7FxMAMwgDKAB9BjcLKAB+HNr66LiIBOSS51sKqtqahubWmuGOwp7bEaa8qAAuVuMIADdBhagV9erN7aqBTxIAe2NUqFWNHUDgtLNmSMmuotTQzIAKVuBN-M7u3yuASCIXSkSycyimz812Bd1MYJoAEoEFlgIdqCczsALsxLv4biCzO8UNh6kREeQoAB6KlQY4Aa2wIBomPOAHdcYCCXDiTAGAAvKRICnU2lVAzHAxAA)

Comment: An awesome and thorough explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kelsny and @jcalz!

I was able to come up with this solution:

```js
export type ChessPiecePromotes = 'Q' | 'R' | 'B' | 'N';
export type ChessPieceWithoutPawn = 'K' | ChessPiecePromotes;
export type ChessPiece = 'P' | ChessPieceWithoutPawn;
export type ChessX = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h';
export type ChessY = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8;

export type AlgebraicMoveNotationTarget = `${ChessX}${ChessY}`
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationDisambiguate = '' | ChessX | ChessY | AlgebraicMoveNotationTarget;
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationCapture = '' | 'x';
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationPromote = `${ChessX}8${ChessPiecePromotes}`;
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationDecoration = '' | '+' | '#';
export type AlgebraicMoveNotationCastle = 'O-O' | 'O-O-O';

export type CheckAlgebraicMoveNotation<T extends string> =
    |
        T extends `${ChessX}${infer C}` ?
            C extends `${AlgebraicMoveNotationCapture}${infer G}` ?
                G extends `${AlgebraicMoveNotationTarget}${infer E}` ?
                    E extends AlgebraicMoveNotationDecoration ? T
                        : never : never : never : never
    |
        T extends `${ChessPieceWithoutPawn}${infer D}` ?
            D extends `${AlgebraicMoveNotationDisambiguate}${infer C}` ?
                C extends `${AlgebraicMoveNotationCapture}${infer G}` ?
                    G extends `${AlgebraicMoveNotationTarget}${infer E}` ?
                        E extends AlgebraicMoveNotationDecoration ? T
                            : never : never : never : never : never
    | T extends AlgebraicMoveNotationPromote ? T : never
    | T extends AlgebraicMoveNotationCastle ? T : never
;

export function notation<T extends string>(move: T extends CheckAlgebraicMoveNotation<T> ? T : never) {
    return move;
}
```